# What caused Realm notification

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Can anybody explain how can I know what operation caused my realm notification trigger?

I have Objects, and I create notifications on Object's changes. These objects can be updated from many places and I'd like to know exact place where it happened

Comment: I don't know about Realm notifications but usually you can send along some user info or id with the notification for the receivers to use f they need to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to tell from within the Realm APIs which object change caused the notification.

One option you have, however, is to create an ignored property on your object and set a value on the object to know who wrote to it. Here's an example:

```
//Class definition
class Stuff: Object{
  @objc dynamic var whatever = ""

  //In memory only
  @objc dynamic var blame = ""
  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["blame"]
  }
}
```

Then elsewhere in your code:

```
//Place #1 where object is changed
let myObject = Stuff()
myObject.blame = "place1"

//Place #2 where object is changed
let myObject = Stuff()
myObject.blame = "place2"
```

Then in your Realm listener, you can access the `blame` property on the object to find out where it was changed:

```
token = myObject.observe { change in
  switch change {
  case .change(let properties):
    for property in properties {
      print(property.blame) //<-- This tells you where it changed
    }
  case .error(let error):
    print("An error occurred: \(error)")
  case .deleted:
    print("The object was deleted.")
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps. Good luck!